# ASP.Net WCF Service with no App_Code

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I want to create a WCF Service for use on my ASP.Net website (not project) that either has no codebehind file, which was is an option for a traditional asmx style service but doesn't *appear* to be for wcf services, or which stores it's code in a separate code project and is just exposed by the svc file.

I tried just moving the code file from app_code into my separate project but couldn't figure out how to link them, as removing the codebehind attribute from the svc file immediately throws an error.

Comment: This is why to not use web sites for serious work. BTW, using a web service is serious work.

Comment: You should probably look at building a WCF Service Application, if you want to host/isolate the service outside your website.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have your SVC file in your web project point to a class that's contained in a separate DLL.  You don't have to have your SVC "code behind" in your App_Code directory.  It's very easy to do.  Your SVC file just needs to have a single attribute - `Service`.  Here's a sample of one that I use where I work:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Service="My.Qualified.Service.Class.Name" %>
```

I do not have any code behind in the App_Code folder.  All of the logic for this SVC is contained in a separate DLL (which happens to be `My.Qualified.Service.Class.dll`).  My service name is the name of the implementing class; that's the only caveat.

My web.config (inside `system.serviceModel`) references this service like so:

```
<service name="My.Qualified.Service.Class.Name">
    <endpoint address=""
     binding="webHttpBinding"
     contract="My.Qualified.Service.Class.IName" />
</service>
```

My service's logic is straight-forward WCF code after that.  My `IName` interface defines my operations; `Name` implements them.

I hope this helps!

Comment: This looks good except... is there anyway I can get away with not having the reference in web.config (like you can with asmx files)?  Well, asmx files have a kind of global entry <add path="*.asmx" verb="*"  etc...

Comment: Hmm...been a while since I worked with asmx files.  I guess you could configure the WCF service in code.  Just curious, why don't you want to configure the service in your config?

Comment: We have a single ASP.Net website which we call our "shell".  We "host" several custom utilities/applications in this shell.  They all share a base masterpage, app_theme, logging/security functions, etc... Since this code is maintained by multiple developers and supports many systems we try to keep each application as seperate as possible (keep all of it's pages, user controls, web services in a single folder).  DLL's still go in the Bin directory, but thats about as much overlap as we have.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a video that demonstrates how to implement WCF in a way that (I think) allows you to do what you are asking about. You can separate your contracts, services, etc so that you can easily reuse your service. You would need to be able to add references so maybe converting the site to a web app may be the best thing. This would allow to keep your service in a separate project and simply expose it in your web app after referencing your service projects dll.

http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=122