# ServiceReference a self hosted WCF service

Tags: asp.net, ajax, wcf, web-services

I am currently maintaining and developing a website which uses a lot of webservices in an ajax way.

Registering of the services is done in the **aspx** like this:

```
<asp:ScriptManagerProxy id="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        <services>    
            <asp:ServiceReference Path="WebServices/WSAdministrator.asmx"></asp:ServiceReference>
        </services>
</asp:ScriptManagerProxy>
```

and consuming the services in the javascript is done like this

```
WSAdministrator.GetConsumerClubInfo(ConsumerClubId,
                                    OnSucceededToGetConsumerClubInfo,
                                    OnFailedToGetConsumerClubInfo);
```

I want to know if I can reference a self-hosted WCF service(on the same machine) this easily.

any suggestions?

**EDIT**: The WCF service is running on a windows service, it exposes both webHttpBinding and basicHttpBinding endpoints.

After Reading [ASP.Net WCF Service with no App_Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235957/asp-net-wcf-service-with-no-app-code) , I realized that I should just create an svc file which will act as a reference to the service.

I created this svc file:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Service="MyService.Namespace.Contract" %>
```

and in the web.config file I added these lines:

```
        <services>
        <service name="MyService.Namespace.Contract">
            <endpoint address="setAddress" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MyService.Namespace.ContractInterface"/>
        </service>
    </services>
```

The address is working, but when I try to access the reference from the svc, I get the following error:

> The type '', provided as the Service attribute value in the
>   ServiceHost directive could not be found.

What am I missing here?

**Note:** There have been some nice answers, but all to things I already know, my question is about how to reference my Self Hosted WCF service using asp.net so that I can use it from javascript, that's all, and for that I still have no answers...

I saw some replies to similar questions telling **there should be an IIS hosted service acting as a "pipe" to the actual service**, and then the ScriptManager should reference it, Maybe that's the only answer...

Comment: I think you might be mixing up AJAX-Enabled WCF Services with calling a WCF service via AJAX?

Comment: hmmm... maybe I am? in the end I just want to call a WCF web service from javascript, as written in the question. it works with an asmx web service by referencing it's asmx file, but now I don't know what ServiceReference to write, because I have no svc file.

Comment: I'm not sure either.  Have you tried putting the endpoint's address as defined by the Windows Service host in?  I don't know if that will work, but it might.  Also note that it needs to be on the same machine (or same domain) as you can't do cross-domain calls.

Comment: Are you suggesting adding a basicHttpBinding endpoint and then adding a ServiceReference to the address? I think something is missing here...

Comment: No.  I'm suggesting trying to add the URI that the your service is listening on (as defined in the Window Service's app.config file or programatically within the service host) and see if that works.  What is the endpoint address for your Windows Service hosted WCF?

Comment: I've posted some new info in my question, hope it can help you help me  :)

Comment: Is MyService.Namespace.Contract that you put for the Service attribute correct?

Comment: I think it is. it's the namespace and the "contract" is the class which implements the interface contract.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are self hosting your WCF Service you do not use .SVC file, but create the service host in your windows service's OnStart method in the following way.

```
WebServiceHost myServiceHost = null;
if (myServiceHost != null)
{
    myServiceHost.Close();
}

myServiceHost = new WebServiceHost(typeof(YourClassName));
myServiceHost.Open();
```

If you want to host your service to support WebHttpBinding then the hosting class should be WebServiceHost and if you want to host wsHttpBinding or any other you should use ServiceHost.

Once service starts running clients can connect to it.

The following [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx) contains step by step process for doing it.

If you have to support RESTful service that is able to talk to using AJAX and Jquery then you should go with WebServiceHost and you would decorate your operation contracts in the following way.

```
[ServiceContract()]
public interface IMyInterface
{
   [OperationContract]
   [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
   ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
   UriTemplate = "GetArray",
   BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
   MyArray[] GetArray();
}
```

You can find some info on this even in the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142035/how-to-consume-wcf-service-running-as-windows-service-in-ajax-client).

Comment: hi coolcake, my Service works ok. it is up and running. the question is how can I integrate it into asp.net as a service reference so I can use it from javascript.

Comment: Follow the following link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx. With out seeing any of your code it hard to find out what your problem is..

Comment: You need RESTful WCF Service to able to call your application using javascript.

Comment: I will gladly put any piece of code needed, but I'm not sure what to put here, because as I said the Service is running, I think this is a configuration problem. about your second comment, ASP.NET makes it possible to reference a local web service and then use it in the javascript, so it doesn't have to be a RESTful service.

Comment: Im confused with what you want. Or may be Im not getting your question. Yes your correct if you want to access the service through proxy you dont need restful service

Comment: You say service running in windows service and you want to reference it in ASP.net project?

Comment: The web service is exposing both RESTful and SOAP endpoints. I want to know if I can reference the SOAP endpoint in ASP.Net so that I can use the web service from Javascript. (as mentioned in the question)

Comment: You need to have mex publishing enabled and the service in which your wcf server is running should be online and then in the ASP.net project select add service reference then it should work. If your service is not running then it will not work.

Comment: Ok, so I have a service reference in the project, it is working from C# code, but how can I make it work from javascript code, as described in the question?

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can and it would look like this with WCF,

```
<asp:ServiceReference Path="~/WSAdministrator.svc" />
```

See [Here](http://www.ajaxtutorials.com/ajax-tutorials/expose-wcf-service-to-javascript-in-asp-net-3-5/) and [here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=235)  for some examples.

Comment: I'm not sure if I've done something wrong... but the WCF is self hosted and I have no svc file...

Comment: Do you have any idea what to do when there is no svc file but the WCF service is self-hosted in the same machine as the IIS...?

Comment: .svc files are when u want to host wcf in IIS or Windows Activation Services(WAS). Is there anything preventing you from using either of those two in hosting the service?

Comment: I've posted some new info in my question, hope it can help you help me  :)

Comment: Are you sure svc files are just when hosting in IIS, the link I've put in the question says it can also refer to code not on the IIS. anyway, the service needs to be self-hosted, as it is IIS independant.